# Update the column by ignoring first five digits in the value field

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, insert-update

How to update the column by ignoring few digits in the value field.
For example I am having value `BKIH-10A` in the column `SECTION-ID`.
I want only `10A` in that field, how can I remove `BKIH-` from that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
Declare @SECTION_ID varchar(20)
Set @SECTION_ID='BKIH-10A'
Select substring(@SECTION_ID,charindex('-',@SECTION_ID)+1,len(@SECTION_ID))

Result 
10A
```

I assume that you want the characters from the symbol  `-`

or

if you can just hard code the position of the starting string in the substring expression

```
 substring(SECTION_ID,6,len(SECTION_ID)
```

Comment: THank you very much but I am having 21000 rows of section data and each row is different. Your assumption is correct, i want the characters from the symbol "-". i have to replace "10A" in the place of "BKIH-10A".

Comment: Instead of `@SECTION_ID` replace it with your column name `SECTION_ID` and it should work